# JetBrains setting for commenting block of code with indent

Tags: refactoring, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, auto-indent, block-comments

I have a problem with my JetBrains product which is not correctly comment block of code with `Ctrl + Shift + /`.

When I use this to comment my code it will add `/*` and `*/` in first column instead of my code indent so then after using reformatting  my code these `/*` and `*/` will came to indent place of my code and my code which is commented now will more indent.

Sorry for my bad Description. I will show you an example.

```
        code
        to
        be
        comment
```

after commenting

```
/*
        code
        to
        be
        comment
*/
```

after refactor code

```
        /*
                    code
                    to
                    be
                    comment
        */
```

Comment: What language is that? AFAIK such option has to be implemented on per language basis. PHP and JavaScript have that for sure. One note though: that option is for line comments, not block comment. Block comments (which is what you have here in your question) will start when selection begins and when code/selection ends.

Comment: this is in javascript lang. and I will select these lines from beginning to end

Comment: So .. what you may do right now: select line not from very end, but from actual first letter in that line. Try how it will work that way. From what I know, there is no such option for block comments, only for line ones The option for line comments: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Code Generation | Line comment at first column`